# Apache spark in memory caching

Tags: java, caching, apache-spark

Spark caches the working dataset into memory and then performs computations at memory speeds. Is there a way to control how long the working set resides in RAM?

I have a huge amount of data that is accessed through the job. It takes time to load the job initially to RAM and when the next job arrives, it has to load all the data again to RAM which is time consuming.  Is there a way to cache the data forever(or for specified time) into RAM using Spark?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To uncache explicitly, you can use  [RDD.unpersist()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)

If you want to share cached RDDs across multiple jobs you can try the following:

1. Cache the RDD using a same context and re-use the context for other jobs.  This way you only cache once and use it many times
2. There are 'spark job servers' that exist to do the above mentioned functionality. Checkout [Spark Job Server](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) open sourced by Ooyala.
3. Use an external caching solution like [Tachyon](http://tachyon-project.org/)

I have been experimenting with caching options in Spark.  You can read more here : http://sujee.net/understanding-spark-caching/

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the caching option for an RDD. RDD.cache(MEMORY_ONLY)

Spark automatically clears when no other action requires that RDD.

There is no option to cache an RDD for a specified time.

Please check out below link

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#which-storage-level-to-choose

Comment: Can it be handled through java by pausing the execution of the daemon which is loading RDD into cache?

Comment: I am not sure about manually pausing the daemons.   Are you looking to reuse the datasets between consecutive jobs?

Comment: @samthebest can you help me in understanding if there is a possible way to cache RDD for a specific time in memory instead clearing it from cache and loading it everytime a fresh job runs?